# Prettify code inside a textarea

Tags: javascript

i have found this project

http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

i've tested it and it works fine

but it only works with (`<pre>`)

i want use it with (`<textarea>`)

but if i replace `<pre>` to `<textarea>`

it's not working !!

So how to use this script with textarea?

Comment: Textarea contains just plain old text.  No formatting.  You need a rich text editor for syntax highlighting. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla

Comment: A textarea is very different from a static text, I don't think you will get this script to work. A search for "hightlight code textarea" should give you some results.

Comment: Ok, so how to fix this problem? can i replace textarea with another html tag that do the same job? ( i allow my users to edit their html codes, so i am using textarea ) Do you know any other idea ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Have you tried [codemirror](http://codemirror.net/)?

It does what you want: *prettify* code in textarea.

Comment: hey Prasanth, code mirror seems to add lot of divs and hence it could hit performance if the code in the text area grows.
Also it is adding a scroll bar which makes it difficult for customization.
Do you have any suggestions?